# SQLite Database External Attach

Tags: android, android-layout, sqlite

Im having a database file with extension .s3db which has been created using SQLite Administrator. I want to connect to the database with my android application. I have placed my database in the assets folder. What is the code that I need to write to open the database?

Comment: did you try googling on this topic?

Comment: ya but its providing me solutions where the database is created using statements in java......but my database is already created but its not opening.....

Comment: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ship an Android application with a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As searched before, the result is that, after installing software, we should copy our database that is in `assets` folder to `/data/data/your_package/` folder and then use it easily. For this, i use the code as below to copy the database in runtime.

```
    if (!new File("/data/data/" + this.getPackageName()
            + "/database.sqlite").exists()) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("data/data/"
                    + this.getPackageName() + "/database.sqlite");
            InputStream in = getAssets().open("databases/dic.db");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int readBytes = 0;

            while ((readBytes = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
                out.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);

            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

You should place this code, in your MainActivity's `onCreate` function. You can easily use your own database in whole of your project. To access your database, you can use the code as follow :

```
SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(
                "/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/database.sqlite",
                null);

Cursor cursor = sqliteDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table", null); // example of query
```

Enjoy it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some complete tutorials which show step-by-step procedure of accessing a database stored in **assets** folder:

---

[use-existing-sqlite-database-in-android](http://davehiren.blogspot.com/2011/12/use-existing-sqlite-database-in-android.html)

---

[using-your-own-sqlite-database](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

---

BTW if you want to use your manually created database(which will be in sdcard) just access it like:

```
File dbfile = new File("/sdcard/Your_db_File" ); 
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
```